# Remove default styles for extension tx_felogin_pi1

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I just installed a fresh new install of typo3, and i noticed there is a small CSS file in the header with this lines:

```
/* default styles for extension "tx_felogin_pi1" */
.tx-felogin-pi1 label {
    display: block;
}
```

This seems like such a waste. A whole HTTP request for this instruction. How could I get rid of it?

I could uninstall the felogin extension, but if I need to use it for my website It would come back. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1._CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE >
```

to your template.